# How to run project React with Express.js and Axios.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

i have a problem, i'm creating a project that use Express, but i dont know how to run that project, i trying to use `concurrently` but fail...

What i want is get the names of the URL `http://localhost:9000/people` (generate by `express.js`) and insert in `persons` in the `this.state`.

Someone would can help me?

my `package.json`:

```js
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:9000"
}
```

my `app.js` with `axios.js`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const axios = require("axios");

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      elementsPerPage: 15,
      currentPage: 0,
      persons: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:9000/person").then(res => {
      this.setState({persons: res.data})})
  }
  ....
```

my `express.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/person', (req, res) => {
  res.send([{ id: 0, name: "123" },
    { id: 1, name: "123" },
    { id: 2, name: "123" },
    { id: 3, name: "123" },
    { id: 4, name: "123" },
    { id: 5, name: "123" },
    { id: 6, name: "123" },
    { id: 7, name: "123" },
    { id: 8, name: "123" },
    { id: 9, name: "123" },
    { id: 10, name: "123" },
    { id: 11, name: "123" }]
)
});



app.listen(9000, () => console.log('Running server on 9000'));
```

Already trying `npm run dev` `npm start` and not was.

Comment: So when do your problem start. I mean do your app fail, is transpilation failing, or can you not acces the data (is the axios call failing?)

Comment: So you mention that you are running npm start. If you have not modified anything in react-scripts/start.js this will transpile your react app and start a development server. This server however is not the express server you have created, so you should start that separately.

Comment: @the_cheff Gives that error: `Line 15:  'peoples' is not defined  no-undef`, I execute the two.

Comment: Short anwer: You are propably using 'peoples' instead of 'people' on line 15. 
Long answer: 
I am not sure what 'peoples' is i do not see it anywhere in your posted code (are you talking about the same variable when you say people, peoples and person?).

It does look like a linting error. So i guess this happens at transpile time (so you can not even access the app right?). This means that you are using a variable before you define it. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef

So look in your code and find places where you are using peoples without defining it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
componentDidMount() {
axios.get("/people").then(res => { //dont use full address
  this.setState({peoples: res.data})})
}
```

if this doesnt work,
try following this tutorial [How to get create-react-app to work with a Node.js back-end API](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-create-react-app-work-with-a-node-backend-api-7c5c48acb1b0)